# Cannot Read struct with string from PLC using s7netplus c#

Tags: c#, .net, struct, plc

im trying to read this data block from Siemens S1500 PLC using s7netplus libary

and my mapped code struct looks like this

```
public struct testStruct
    {
        public bool Campo_Bool1;
        public bool Campo_Bool2;
        public short Campo_Int1;
        public short Campo_Int2;
        public int Campo_Dint1;
        public int Campo_Dint2;
        public double Campo_Real1;
        public double Campo_Real2;
        public string Campo_String1;
        public string Campo_String2;
    }
```

I'm using this command to read the struct

```
teststruct = (testStruct)client.ReadStruct(typeof(testStruct), 1);
```

Error message is "Please add S7StringAttribute to the string field"

How can I read this Structure?

Thank you very much.

EDIT 2.0:
This is my new struct

```
public struct testStruct
    {
        public bool Campo_Bool1;
        public bool Campo_Bool2;
        public short Campo_Int1;
        public short Campo_Int2;
        public int Campo_Dint1;
        public int Campo_Dint2;
        public float Campo_Real1;
        public float Campo_Real2;
        [S7String(S7StringType.S7String,8)]
        public string Campo_String1;
        [S7String(S7StringType.S7String,8)]
        public string Campo_String2;
    }
```

New error message is "Received error from PLC: Address out of range."

This is my DB

[image]

Comment: Okay, so have you *tried* adding `S7StringAttribute` to the string fields? (You need to specify how much space to reserve.) Please show us what you've tried and what happened.

Comment: @JonSkeet I added EDIT 2.0 in my question.

Answer (score 0):

From the s7netplus wiki ([here](https://github.com/S7NetPlus/s7netplus/wiki)), ReadStruct/WriteStruct methods do not support strings:

[image]